# `gcc -E -P -C` adds extra comments

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to run CPP on a JS file, which contains comments. I want to keep comments so I'm using `-C` argument of `gcc -E -P`, but GCC or CPP then adds extra comments. Here's how to reproduce:

```
➜  cpp-test  ls
➜  cpp-test  touch empty
➜  cpp-test  gcc -E -P -x assembler-with-cpp -C empty -o empty.out 
➜  cpp-test  cat empty.out
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */
/* This header is separate from features.h so that the compiler can
   include it implicitly at the start of every compilation.  It must
   not itself include <features.h> or any other header that includes
   <features.h> because the implicit include comes before any feature
   test macros that may be defined in a source file before it first
   explicitly includes a system header.  GCC knows the name of this
   header in order to preinclude it.  */
/* We do support the IEC 559 math functionality, real and complex.  */
/* wchar_t uses ISO/IEC 10646 (2nd ed., published 2011-03-15) /
   Unicode 6.0.  */
/* We do not support C11 <threads.h>.  */
➜  cpp-test
```

How can I tell GCC/CPP to not generate those comments?

Comment: Works fine for me. empty.out is empty (file size 0). I am using gcc 4.3.4, gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973.

Comment: @Bort, Doesn't work fine for me (`empty.out` has comments). I am using gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2.

Comment: The comment comes from implicit include of `features.h`, as state in comment.

Comment: I'm using `gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]` and it definitely includes comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments seem to contain the explanation of what's going on, particularly the parts that say `compiler can include it implicitly at the start of every compilation` and `GCC knows the name of this header in order to preinclude it`.

There's a [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59566) that looks very similar to your question that was resolved by the use of `-nostdinc`.

Comment: There is a more recent bug report.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197881/ .